# Workbook slow and crashing due to VBA code? Anyway to stop this/speed this up?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code in my worksheet.
The code causes the spreadsheet to works slow and crash and it also takes ages to open. I am brand new to VBA and may not be coding this correctly. Is there a better way of structuring my code to prevent this from happening?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Message
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
 If Target.Address = "$K$3" Then
    If Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row < 5 Then
    Range("A5").Select
    Else
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$I$3" Then
    If Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row < 5 Then
    Range("A5").Select
    Else
    Range("A9").Select
    End If
    End If


     If Target.Address = "$N$2" Then
    If Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row < 5 Then
        Range("A5").Select
    Else
        Range("A7").Select
    End If
    End If


       'Clear Search Box
    If Target.Address = "$N$3:$O$3" Then
    Target.Value = ""
    End If




Exit Sub

Message:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Exit Sub

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Message
On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False



'Insert Depot Memo Data for user
 Dim oCell As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo Message
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column I has changed
        If Not GetWb("Depot Memo", ws2) Then Exit Sub

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Target
                Set oCell = .Range("J1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Find(What:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not oCell Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False

                    'Set Format of cell
                    targetCell.Font.Name = "Arial"
                    targetCell.Font.Size = "10"

                    With targetCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                    End With

                    With targetCell.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                    End With

                    With targetCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
                    .Weight = xlThin
                    End With

                    With targetCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
                    .Weight = xlThin
                    End With


                    targetCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
                     targetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -2)
                     targetCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -7)
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If





 'Prompt missed on sale
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Value = "Issue Complete" Then
    If Target.Cells.Count < 8 Then
    Dim MSG1 As Variant

    MSG1 = MsgBox("Did Item Miss On-Sale?", vbYesNo, "Feedback")
    If MSG1 = vbYes Then
    Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Yes"
    Else
    Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "No"
    End If

    Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Date - Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    End If
    End If



 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
 Call PhoneBook2
 End If






'Send Email - Receipt of Issue

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
If Target.Cells.Count < 4 Then

Call SendEmail0

End If
End If



'Send Email - Status Change

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
If Target.Cells.Count < 4 Then

Call SendEmail

End If
End If



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True







Exit Sub



Message:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Exit Sub

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
If ActiveCell.Value = "(Turn Off Emails)" Then
UserForm1.Show
End If

End Sub






Function GetWb(wbNameLike As String, WS As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        If Wb.Name Like "*" & wbNameLike & "*" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "Depot Memo"
            Set WS = Wb.Worksheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not WS Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see how many times each subroutine is being invoked?

Answer (score 1):

When you select a cell in Selection Change Event code, the selection change event gets triggered again.
Same thing happens when you change the value of a cell in Sheet Change Event, the same event gets triggered again.
So in the background event codes gets triggered multiple time which makes codes execution slow.

To deal with this, you should use Application.EnableEvents = False to avoid the event code to be triggered again.
But remember to enable the events again by Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: I was thinking along those lines too, but the `SelectionChange` will only fire at most twice as far as I can see, or possibly call the `Change`, which also will only fire at most twice - **unless** the code which isn't shown (e.g. subroutine `SendEmail`) is also changing things on the same sheet.  Definitely needs the `EnableEvents` but I think there is more to this.  P.S. +1 because I think this will be the **major** reason for the problem.

Comment: The number of sub routines are being called inside those event codes and you never know if the multiple cells are being selected or changed in those sub routines as well which looks quite obvious considering the existing codes pattern. :)